# what is the best way to handle selector keys?

Tags: java, multithreading, selector, pool

When using selector and NIO channels,
Can I have some (fixed) threads to handle each of the readable keys ? (i.e. one thread per each readable key of each channel ?)

for example:
 while (true) {

```
int readyChannels = m_selector.select(1000);
if (0 == readyChannels)
{
    continue;
}

Set<SelectionKey> keys = m_selector.selectedKeys();                     
Iterator<SelectionKey> keyIterator = keys.iterator();

while(keyIterator.hasNext()) {  
SelectionKey key = keyIterator.next();
keyIterator.remove();

    if (key.isReadable()) {                     
    ...
             ****  WHAT CAN I WRITE HERE TO HANDLE EACH READABLE CHANNEL KEY ONCE ?
             **** BECAUSE IF I OPEN NEW THREAD IT WILL NOT FINISH TO HANDLE THE KEY AND I WILL GET
             ****  TO THIS CODE AGAIN...
    ...
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a NIO based server few years ago which proved to be very high throughput both from amount of data processed and number of clients connected. I can share my experience based on that.

**Please note that in your particular scenario this may not apply 100% so make tweaks as appropriate.**

Yow will be better of if you do not do processing of data in the code below

**So change this to**

```
   if (key.isReadable()) {                     
    ...
             ****  WHAT CAN I WRITE HERE TO HANDLE EACH READABLE CHANNEL KEY ONCE ?
             **** BECAUSE IF I OPEN NEW THREAD IT WILL NOT FINISH TO HANDLE THE KEY AND I WILL GET
             ****  TO THIS CODE AGAIN...
    ...
    }
```

**TO**

```
   if (key.isReadable()) {                     
         // Sudo logic
         // Add the selection key to a thread pool with blocking queue.
         // Now your threads in the thread pool will do the heave IO task of reading bytes 
         // Once the bytes are read you if they need further processing like parsing out what 
         // Kind of message is it. You can use another thread pool that parses the data

    }
```

If you follow the two thread pool approach you have two benefits.

- Delegating the heavy lifting of doing network I/O that reading from a channel to a thread pool.
- Second thread pool further improves the performance because it takes the responsibility of parsing the messages from bytes read from first thread pool.

You may have to do some thread pool tuning as suitable for your situation.

I hope it helps :)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help. but when I'm using thread pool (ExecutorService) the main loop which go over the keys is called again with isReadable key before the thread (from the thread pool which need to handle the read data from the channel). so how you solve it ?

Comment: I hope I am getting your question right. It will not have any affect. At the max you are adding same key to the task queue twice. It means that when you process the same key after you have already read the data from channel associated with that key there will be no data to read. Does that help?

Comment: Hi, pls look: void run () {
 while (true) {
     SelectionKey key = q.take();
  myConnectionReadingNetworkHandling = key.attachment();
  executor.execute(myConnectionReadingNetworkHandling);
 }
} 
If i will implement the code like this, there is a chance for 2 threads to handle the same key (beacuse the execute will not start at the momoemt of calling ...)

Comment: Yeah you are right. As I said it's been few years. I just verified my old code. I am checking if that SelectionKey has already been added to the work queue or not. If not than I am adding it.

Comment: Hi, thanks again. so if I understand we need one thread to get the Selectionkeys from the selector and push it into the Q, another thread to get the SelectionKeys from the Q and invoke thread thread (from the thread pool), and X threads (according to the thread pool capacity (total: 2+x threads) am I right ?

Comment: I think you yes. But I will mention again just to make sure it's clear.  One thread checks which Keys are ready and adds them to a Q. This Q is consumed by a thread pool and doing heavy lifting of reading bytes of network. :)

Comment: Do you think it answered your question